# How to change MAPI MessageClass in Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, email

I am trying to get Exchange 2010 to change the MessageClass (PR_MESSAGE_CLASS) of an incoming message to that of my custom form (IPM.Note.MyCustom) when the incoming message has a certain header set. (`X-MyCustomHeader: Yes`)

I have seen some information about setting another MIME header (`Content-Class:`) that Exchange will use to set the MessageClass, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  (I've seen examples that use `Content-Class: MyCustom` and `Content-Class: urn:content-class:custom.MyCustom`)

I've even looked into writing a transport agent with C#, and I did find a `MapiMessageClass` property on the `EmailMessage` class, but it's read-only.  I also looked at added a MAPI property in a TNEF section, but the Exchange API does not offer a way to create a TNEF section if one does not already exist.  (And most mail from the Internet doesn't.)

There's got to be a way to do this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/exchangesvrsecuremessaginglegacy/thread/2161e118-3cb0-4fa6-a2d1-d7266b2928ac/) explains how to do it.  You need to create a transport rule that modifies the Content-type header of the message.

Their solution is to:

> 1. Go to a client PC, install Network Monitor
> 2. Open outlook. Open Network Monitor and “Start Capture”
> 3. Send an item from outlook [the item needs to be converted]
> 4. Go to “Network Monitor”, find the frame called “MIME” in “Frame Summary” pane, and select it. Then check the “Frame Details” pane, find a row like “Header: Content-Type: Text/Calendar”
> 5. Re-do steps 2-4, this time send an item with “IPM.Note.Microsoft.Voicemail.UC” Message Class. Then go to find which “Content-Type” [???/???] it represents in “Network Monitor”
> 6. Now go to Exchange server EMC, create a new transport rule. Example
>
> Condition: When a message header contains specific words
>
> ```
>                                Content-Type                     Text/Calendar
> ```
>
> Action: Set header with value
>
> ```
>        Content-Type    ???/???
> ```
>
> 7. OK. Enable the rule

Comment: As I stated in my question, I've already tried setting the Content-Type header to no effect.  That header does get set, but Exchange is not using that header's information to change the Message Class.